# Programmatically change LAYOUT color in @drawable xml

Tags: android

I've read through a lot of questions on here about programmatically changing the color of a drawable, but they seem to not relate to actual layouts.  When I try this:

```
RelativeLayout firstWord = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.topBG);
Drawable layoutBG = firstWord.getDrawable();
firstWord = buttonBackground.mutate();
firstWord.setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

I get this error:

> The method getDrawable() is undefined for the type RelativeLayout

I used a drawable to give my layout rounded corners but part of the app is that the background color changes on every click, so I need to know how to change the color in code.

Before moving to a drawable, I was using:

```
firstWord.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Here is my drawable:

round_corners.xml

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="#000000" />

    <padding 
        android:left="1dp" 
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp" 
        android:bottom="1dp" />

    <corners 
        android:radius="25dp" />

</shape>
```

And here's my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VulgarActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/bottomBG"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
        >
    </View> 
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBG"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners" 
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Push"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="50sp" 
        android:shadowColor="#080808"
        android:shadowRadius="10.0"
        android:shadowDx="5"
        android:shadowDy="5"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help :)

Just a thought:

I could change the color value in "round_corners.xml" to an @color reference (eg:

```
android:color="@color/switcher"
```

and putting this in the 'color' folder in values

```
<color name="switcher">#000000</color>
```

Would it be easier to programmatically change the color that way?

Comment: can you show the xml for the RelativeLayout ?

Comment: ok got it. i'll have a look.

Comment: @j2emanue  Thanks in advance... just edited my original post.  Look at the bottom and let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

can you use these line instead, im getting the background drawable on the second line:

```
RelativeLayout firstWord = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.topBG);
Drawable layoutBG = firstWord.getBackground();
buttonBackground = buttonBackground.mutate();
buttonBackground.setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: crap, didn't notice I typoed that.  it's not 'buttonbackground', it's still 'firstWord'.  edited my OP now.  Will try it now with the correction, though

Comment: OK, so it accepts the following code but it changes the background to black then nothing else:

    Drawable layoutBG = firstWord.getBackground();
         layoutBG.setColorFilter(color,Mode.MULTIPLY);